# JPA equivalent of JDO getExtent

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jdo

In JDO you can define the Extent of a query,

```
PersistenceManager lPM = thePMF.getPersistenceManager();
lPM.getFetchPlan().setMaxFetchDepth( -1 );
Extent< AreaT> lExtent = lPM.getExtent( AreaT.class, true );
Query lQuery = lPM.newQuery( lExtent, "ParentArea == null" );
```

What is the equivalent in JPA?

I'm pretty new to JPA and wondering if there's an equivalent or if its just only don't directly with a query string.

Answer (score 0):

No need to define an Extent with JPA.

For example here is a method I use to find all objects of a particular class

```
public List<T> findAll() {
   javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
   cq.select(cq.from(AreaT.class));
   return getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
}
```

Comment: Excellent. I had a feeling this was the case. Thanks for the CriteriaQuery example also, pretty cool stuff :3

Answer (score 0):

As you thought, it's only done directly with a query in JPA; that API has no equivalent of Extent. Also you don't have the ability to exclude subclasses in JPA (well you can but have to put type restrictions in the WHERE clause!), whereas in JDO it is a simple boolean.

Comment: Yeah, I read up on subclasses and Queries and found out about the polymorphic nature of JPA queries and subclass restrictions. Good to know I'm on the right track, cheers!